# TFS 2013 CI build from a remote Git repo

Tags: windows, git, tfs, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration

Is it possible to schedule a **CI Build** in TFS server to clone a "**remote** Git repository" (i.e. from gitHub or gitLab) and run the build??

I know that `TFS 2013` can work with a Self-hosted Git repo. But can i make a "TFS build controller" get the code from a remote repo and build it, like cloning/pulling from github?

I am only interested in running the continous integration build, not in using Visual Studio as a git client. (I use SourceTree as git client)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a self hosted Git repo in TFS and clone your remote repo into it you will be able to configure a build for that folder. Then as part of the "pre-build" script you can run whatever you like to get the right bits to where they need to be.

Ideally you need to customise the build template to run a script pre-get that will sync the repos before TF Build gets the code.

Comment: So i can tell TFS to run a pre-build script in which i launch something like "git clone" and store the files in a specific folder. I tell TFS build service not to perform any checkout or anything, just to compile and run tests in the specific folder? I could schedule one build per hour, something like that. I can't tell it to run the build everytime a push is made to the repo. I am forced to schedule the builds with a timer. Am i right?

Comment: You can create a service hook (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/create-subscription) and I use https://zapier.com/ to wire some stuff up